# Reformatting CSV files in R

Tags: python, r, excel, csv, data-mining

Am trying to create a csv file for data mining where each individual instance has an attribute `subject` which has `40` possible values and a corresponding `grade` also an attribute. Each instance can only have a max of `4` `subjects` and `grade`. How can I create a csv file in `excel` representing each subject `{p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,aa,ab,...}` as a `sub-attribute` of subject with grade `{A,B,C,D,E,F,O}` as the value such that i dont lose the dependence and relationship.

They are apparently arranged `(subject->sub, grade->grd)` as below

```
|id|sex|sub1 |grd1 |sub2 |grd2 |sub3 |grd3 |sub4 |grd4 |
|--|---|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|1 |M  |x    |A    |y    |B    |u    |O    |s    |C    |
|2 |F  |p    |E    |aa   |E    |t    |A    |r    |B    |
|3 |M  |q    |B    |z    |D    |aa   |A    |v    |C    |
|4 |F  |t    |D    |ab   |O    |y    |B    |u    |A    |
```

what I want to transform the attribute to

```
|id|sex|subject                                        |
|--|---|-----------------------------------------------|
|1 |M  |x    |A    |y    |B    |u    |O    |s    |C    |
|2 |F  |p    |E    |aa   |E    |t    |A    |r    |B    |
|3 |M  |q    |B    |z    |D    |aa   |A    |v    |C    |
|4 |F  |t    |D    |ab   |O    |y    |B    |u    |A    |
```

thanks in advance

Comment: **why**? no application will be able to read this format. Because it's **not CSV** anymore.

Comment: Those two tables look identical except for the column headings, so it's difficult to understand what type of transformation you're looking for.  Can you clarify?  Generally large scale transformations in Excel tend to be harder than using a tool like OpenRefine or a language like Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has since been long but hope this helps someone else. As @Anony-Mousse noted, the format ceases to be a csv data format. Data structures such as dictionaries can be helpful for this sort of representation. There are two possible alternative here, you can create nested dictionaries and lists or the representation of the data can be in wide format. For a language like R, to transform the data into long fomart you can refer to this link using the reshape package. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-reshape-my-data-in-r/